# Why does Apple's website not make extensive use of CSS3 fonts?

Tags: web-browsing, websites, html, css

Ever since Steve Jobs published his [Thoughts on Flash](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/), I've always seen Apple as advocators of open web standards. Scrolling halfway down the [What is Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/what-is.html) page seems to confirm this notion.

So, why does Apple overwhelmingly use images for their headers? For example,

[image: whatis_title.png]

and on Retina displays,

[image: whatis_title_2x.png]

Wouldn't it make sense, with respect to both open web standards and page load time, to instead link to the fonts in a CSS file?

Comment: There are many ways to do web development. It will be difficult, if not impossible to definitively say why Apple uses images instead of regular CSS-styled text. Chances are it comes back to backwards compatibility, or more granular control over display. Again, this is *just a guess*.

Comment: We're not Apple; we don't know why they do or don't do certain things. The best answer we can give you, I'm afraid, is "Because they choose not to." Anything else is speculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has been notably touchy about 3rd-Party use of their fonts in the past and I'm inclined to say they still are.  Apple use to include a few fonts in OS 8, for example, which had Apple-copyrighted design.  You had access to them in that anything that specifically used that font rendered correctly, but if you wanted to be able to select the font in a text document, you had to jump through some hoops and enable it manually.

The font in question is almost definitely Myriad Pro or an Apple derivative.  You "must" purchase a license to use it commercially.

While I generally agree with your assessment of using CSS3 fonts, it seems that Apple may be more concerned with copyright.  Load time differences are probably negligible for most people accessing the Apple site.  I'm sure they have people in Marketing looking at that data.